# ORA-12015: cannot create a fast refresh materialized view from a complex query

Tags: sql, oracle, materialized-views

I am using below query to build a materialized view.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW gcms_business_profile_mview 
BUILD IMMEDIATE  
REFRESH FAST  
        WITH PRIMARY KEY  
        START WITH SYSDATE  
        NEXT (TRUNC (SYSDATE + 1) + 20 / 96)  
AS
SELECT DISTINCT obp.bp_id,
       obp.bp_typ_cd,
       os.spcl_desc,
       obpi.frs_nm,
       obpi.mdl_nm,
       NVL (rep_lst_nm.lst_nm, othr_lst_nm.lst_nm) last_name,
       NVL (rep_lst_nm.lst_nm_typ_id, othr_lst_nm.lst_nm_typ_id)
          last_name_type_id       
  FROM tr_ods.ods_business_parties obp
       LEFT JOIN (  SELECT bp_id,  
                                speciality_id,  
                                updtd_dt,  
                                ROW_NUMBER ()  
                                OVER (PARTITION BY bp_id ORDER BY updtd_dt DESC)  
                                   AS spec_rn  
                           FROM tr_ods.ods_bp_specialty  
                          WHERE updtd_dt IS NOT NULL  
                       ) obs  
               ON obs.bp_id = obp.bp_id  
               AND obs.spec_rn =1 
       LEFT JOIN tr_ods.ods_specialty  os                                       
          ON  os.speciality_id = latest_spec.speciality_id 
          AND    os.delete_flag = 'N'
       LEFT JOIN tr_ods.ods_business_party_individuals obpi   
          ON obpi.bp_id = obp.bp_id
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT obpln1.bp_id,
                obpln1.lst_nm,
                obpln1.lst_nm_typ_id,
                ROW_NUMBER ()
                   OVER (PARTITION BY obpln1.bp_id ORDER BY updtd_dt DESC)
                   AS lst_rn_22
           FROM tr_ods.ods_business_party_last_names obpln1
          WHERE     lst_nm_typ_id = 22
                AND updtd_dt =
                       (SELECT MAX (obpln2.updtd_dt)
                          FROM tr_ods.ods_business_party_last_names obpln2
                         WHERE     obpln2.bp_id = obpln1.bp_id
                               AND obpln2.lst_nm_typ_id = 22)) rep_lst_nm                             
          ON (rep_lst_nm.bp_id = obp.bp_id AND rep_lst_nm.lst_rn_22 = 1)
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT obpln1.bp_id,
                obpln1.lst_nm,
                obpln1.lst_nm_typ_id,
                ROW_NUMBER ()
                   OVER (PARTITION BY obpln1.bp_id ORDER BY updtd_dt DESC)
                   AS lst_rn
           FROM tr_ods.ods_business_party_last_names obpln1
          WHERE     lst_nm_typ_id IN (21, 23)
                AND updtd_dt =
                       (SELECT MAX (obpln2.updtd_dt)
                          FROM tr_ods.ods_business_party_last_names obpln2
                         WHERE     obpln2.bp_id = obpln1.bp_id
                               AND obpln2.lst_nm_typ_id IN (21, 23))) othr_lst_nm                                  
          ON (othr_lst_nm.bp_id = obp.bp_id AND othr_lst_nm.lst_rn = 1)
```

I am getting

> ORA-12015: cannot create a fast refresh materialized view from a complex query error message.

I have already created materialized view logs for all the tables. Could any one please help me in fixing this issue?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `obs` and `os` joins. You don't use their columns in the projection of the MView, and they don't filter the final result in any way (because they're outer joins). So why not remove them? Then there'e no troublesome analytic function and the MView will fast refresh.

Comment: I have to use their columns. The problem is with obs and i am not getting how to resolve it. I have to complete it by 4:30 PM IST.

Comment: Your posted query doesn't show how you use the columns in the MView projection, so it's pretty hard for us to rewrite the query in a way that will be helpful to you. If it's that urgent you should provide us with *all the necessary information*. Although it's only your emergency not ours.

Comment: Its because i was unable to post the whole query.  I have updated it now by removing a left join and adding the ones that is having problem.

Comment: Okay, there's no way this can be made fast refreshable. Not only have you got the forbidden analytic functions but those subqueries with `max()` aggregates aren't allowed either. Unfortunately you need to revisit the business logic in order to build the MView as you required. Alternatively you need to drop the FAST requirement ,or even explore whether you need a MView at all. This query doesn't look like the typical MView use case: are you trying to fix a performance issue which maybe can be fixed through some other approach?

Comment: The business logic behind creating mview is the users wants to see the snapshot of data from some other schema to another schema.

Comment: Also i can not use Complete refresh, as the masters table used in the mview are very huge.

Comment: No, that's the reason for a view. What is the justification for materializing it? But actually, by "business logic" I meant the business rules shaping the SQL, specifically the need for those subqueries

Comment: The logic behind adding the subquery is in one of our tabel we have data that has three status NON-REPORTABLE, REPORTABLE, SOURCE – 21,22,23).
We need to pick the reportable last name. If that is not present then we need to pick the last name with the most recent updated date.

Comment: othr_lst_nm and rep_lst_nm are for the above logic
and obs is for below logic
A person can have more than 1 specialty. We need to pick the most recently updated profile.

Answer (score 0):

[CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW - Restrictions on FAST Refresh](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6002.htm#SQLRF01302)

> **Restrictions on FAST Refresh**
>
> FAST refresh is subject to the following restrictions:
>
> When you specify FAST refresh at create time, Oracle Database verifies
>   that the materialized view you are creating is eligible for fast
>   refresh. When you change the refresh method to FAST in an ALTER
>   MATERIALIZED VIEW statement, Oracle Database does not perform this
>   verification. If the materialized view is not eligible for fast
>   refresh, then Oracle Database returns an error when you attempt to
>   refresh this view.
>
> - Materialized views are not eligible for fast refresh if the defining
>     query contains an **analytic function** or the XMLTable function.
> - Materialized views are not eligible for fast refresh if the defining
>     query references a table on which an XMLIndex index is defined.
> - You cannot fast refresh a materialized view if any of its columns is
>     encrypted.

---

Your query contains an analytic finction:

```
ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY bp_id ORDER BY updtd_dt DESC)
```

therefore you cannot use a fast refresh for this query.

Comment: Is there any other way to perform this. As the master tables are having 70lakh plus data and I cannot use COMPLETE refresh for this mview.

Comment: Yes - just remove `ROW_NUMBER` function from the query. Please post another question about how to rewrite this SQL wihthout using `ROW_NUMBER` or any other analytic functions.

Comment: @krokodilko-- Thanks for the help

Comment: Is it mandatory to create the materialized view log with ROW ID.